# How to properly pull a JSON file using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I want to know how to properly pull the following json file using PHP and store each entry in the json file to my MySQL database.

Here is the JSON file:  https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=400/genre=6014/json

I would also like to do the same thing to the android google play game apps.

Your helps are much appreciated as I can't find a pretty good one around here.  Thanks!

Comment: So you want to have the json data available in php array ?

Comment: whichever that I can use php to turn the json entries and elements to MySQL database.  so, php to pull the json, then php to write the elements into my MySQL database.  if there's one more step in between, please feel free to provide.  thanks!

Comment: Check my answer below ... Thats to store and organize data from json to php .. Then you can store data from php into mysql

Comment: Why does this question have the iOS tag? It's 100% unrelated to iOS.

Comment: same for android? not related so I have edited the tags.

Comment: http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Comment: So what is the problem? Loading a file from a URL? Reading JSON? Writing to a database? And what is your database structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make a column, json_data (doesn't have to be named like this), should be longtext in mysql db.
2. Store your json text to the json_data like you normally do in storing values in mysql.
3. When you retrieve the data from mysql just use php json_decode function to use it like an array

Code:

```
//where $json_data is the column json_data from your mysql:
$json_array = json_decode($json_data); //return object
$json_array = json_decode($json_data, true); //return array
print_r($json_array); //it should print array now;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use php json_decode() to store the json data in a php object or array .. Then it is a normal insert mysql operation to store data in the db ...
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php